# Powershell code to create shortcuts on to startmenu but only include rdsm files

Tags: powershell

I need to create shortcuts of rdsm files from C:\Users\%current user%\AppData\Local\Micro Focus\Rumba\MFrame on to the startmenu under a subfolder named rumba. there are other files in this folder too. Also can I create folder shortcuts and ignore certain files ?

I have something like this now

```
$TargetFile = "$env:SystemRoot\System32\notepad.exe"
$ShortcutFile = "$env:Public\Desktop\Notepad.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume the code you've shown is working to create a shortcut and you now just need to loop through the contents of the folder listed and look for rdsm files.  You would do that like below. (note that I don't know what extension 'RDSM' files use so you'll likely have to change that part of the filter.)

```
$Files = get-childitem -path $AppDataPath -file | Where-object {$_.Extension -eq ".rdsm"}

foreach($file in $files){
  $TargetFile = $file.path
  $ShortcutFile = "$env:Public\Desktop\$($file.name.substring(0,$file.name.length - 4).lnk"
  *rest of your code here*
}
```

The weird string parsing makes your shortcut file work.

Comment: Since the .lnk-extension isn't visible why not leave the original extension?

Comment: Mostly just to avoid having file extensions show up in start menu, which would look a little weird, but no real requirement for that portion.